# Creating a live chat box on a website

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm fairly new to creating a website from scratch, but I have the webserver and the basics of the site already up. What I'm looking to do is add a chatbox for people browsing the site to talk to each other, and I don't even know where to begin to look for information, up to this point I've only learnt php and javascript where once the content is loaded, nothing can be changed, but I've seen plenty of examples of sites that have information that automatically updates as it is changed. Can anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can start with google. i saw a neat open source chat platform based on PHP called RedisChat.

Comment: [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) are a good start.

Comment: Google about it, you need to have a database for this purpose. I recommend you to use PHP, Mysql and JS (use frameworks like JQuery)

Comment: @venkat, You don't *need* a DB... there are other methods, depending on the needs.

Comment: AJAX, thats what allows you to update content after load... it is a technology that can be used through javascript, there are libraries that take care of it and make it easier like jquery (go to api.jquery.com)